# How to change the center of a UI element from top/left to center with Appcelerator?

Tags: animation, layout, appcelerator, positioning

I have a slider with the function below that should in- and decrease the radius of a circle view. Changing the radius works, but the label/circle is "moving" to the right because the left and top positions are the "center" and static and do not change.

**How can I change it that the center position of the label remains the same (and not the left/top corner)?** I have tried anchorPoint, animatedCenter and center but no visible effect. Right now I don't have an animation as the slider is triggering the change in radius.

```
function showRadar(e){
    //$.radarIcon.anchorPoint = {x:0.5, y:0.5}; //no effect
    //$.radarIcon.animatedCenter = {x:0.5, y:0.5}; //no effect
    $.radarIcon.height = e.source.value;
    $.radarIcon.width = e.source.value;
    $.radarIcon.borderRadius = e.source.value / 2;
    $.radarIcon.center = {x:30, y:400}; //no effect
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the circle in another view:

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <View id="container">
            <View id="circle"/>
            <Label id="lbl" text="test"/>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss

```
"Window" : {
    backgroundColor: "white"
}
"Label" : {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#000"
}

"#circle" : {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: "red"
}
"#container" : {
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}
```

index.js

```
function showRadar(e) {
    $.circle.height = e;
    $.circle.width = e;
    $.circle.borderRadius = e / 2;
}

var i = 100;

$.circle.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showRadar(i);
    if (i < 200) {
        i += 20;
    }
})
$.index.open();
```

When you click the circle it will increase size and the text is still centered. I've set the max width of the outer container to 200, so it won't get bigger.